# Execute stored procedure in OUTER APPLY block

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, apply, outer-join

Why I can not use a stored procedure in `OUTER APPLY` block?
I need to get int value from the stored procedure `dbo.GetTeacherId` and use this in `WHERE` clause. Here my code:

```
USE [StudentsDb]

DECLARE @teacherIdOut int;

SELECT   StudentLastName, StudentFirstName, StudentMiddleName, LessonName, Score, TLastName, TFirstName, TMiddleName
FROM     Scores
JOIN Students
ON Scores.StudentId=Students.StudentId
JOIN Lessons
ON Scores.LessonId=Lessons.LessonId
OUTER APPLY
(
    EXECUTE dbo.GetTeacherId 0, 0, @teacherId=@teacherIdOut -- here I get error
    SELECT Teachers.TeacherLastName, Teachers.TeacherFirstName, Teachers.TeacherMiddleName
    FROM Teachers
    WHERE Teachers.TeacherId=@teacherIdOut
)T(TLastName, TFirstName, TMiddleName)
WHERE Score <=3
```

And is there any other way to get the value from the stored procedure?
Here my stored procedure `dbo.GetTeacherId`:

```
USE [StudentsDb]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTeacherId] @lessonId int, @groupId int, @teacherId int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT @teacherId=GroupTeachers.TeacherId
    FROM GroupTeachers
    WHERE GroupTeachers.LessonId=@lessonId AND GroupTeachers.GroupId=@groupId
END
```

Comment: You should use function for that kind of functionality.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic Thank you so much! With the function everything works! How can I confirm your answer as my accepted answer?

Comment: I'll write a more detailed explanation as an answer in few minutes, so you can accept it, and to have for other who stumble on this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stored procedure is not designed for that kind of usage, as it can perform operations other then selecting data, it can work without returning data or it can return different set in different scenarios.

Unlike stored procedures, functions are exactly suited to be used inline with other queries.

You have two options:

A) Create a scalar function that will return only a `TeacherID` and use it in your `WHERE`

```
CREATE FUNCTION udfGetTeacherID
(
    @lessonId int, @groupId int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @teacherId INT;

    SELECT @teacherId = GroupTeachers.TeacherId
    FROM GroupTeachers
    WHERE GroupTeachers.LessonId=@lessonId AND GroupTeachers.GroupId=@groupId;


    RETURN @teacherId;

END
GO
```

B) Create table-valued function that can get you all the data needed and you can just join (apply) on it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION udfGetTeacherName
(
    @lessonId int, @groupId int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT t.TeacherLastName, t.TeacherFirstName, t.TeacherMiddleName
    FROM Teachers t
    INNER JOIN GroupTeachers g ON  T.TeacherID = g.TeacherID
    WHERE g.LessonId=@lessonId AND g.GroupId=@groupId
)
GO
```

Here is some reading:
[Difference between Stored Procedure and Function in SQL Server](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/7EDL150912-Difference-between-Stored-Procedure-and-Function-in-SQL-Server.html)

Comment: Is there an alternative if you don't have permissions to create functions on the server (but you do have permissions to create procedures)?